# Adding an extension to AndroidDriver

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium, appium-android

I am having a difficulty adding an extension to AndroidDriver.

For Web Automation, I am using this approach:

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addExtensions(new File("/path/to/extension.crx"));
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

However, I cannot find a solution for AndroidDriver. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you using Appium to do your automation?  If so, it's not tagged.  If not, why not?  I'm not even certain that the chrome driver for Android has extensions, but if it does, this is an interesting question.

Comment: @BillHileman sorry, yes, I am using Appium, forgot to tag it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome For Android/iOS **Does not** support Chrome-desktop extensions.

Comment: Are you trying to automate browser tests? Selenium is probably what you need.